# How to intercept and handle Exceptions thrown by Quarkus

Tags: kotlin, http, exception, quarkus

I have an endpoint to upload files, which is never reached when the payload violates the limit in the `quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size` property.

I'm receiving an HTTP 413 Exception, which is fine, but I want to catch this exception and update its body to add a custom message.

I've tried using ExceptionMapper and doesn't work, even the endpoint is never called.

Also, I tried using a filter to validate the payload, but never gets into the payload if the payload size is bigger than `quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size` property value.

I want to use the `quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size` property to validate the payload size, but adding a custom message to the Exception thrown by Quarkus.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the exact exception in the ExceptionMapper? You may see it in the logs. Also, consider using @Priority because the internal exception mapper could be called.